# Lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing the following code and is working correctly.

```
edge(s,a,300,300/500 * 60, 300*1,plane).
edge(s,a,300,300/120 * 60, 300*3/4,train).
edge(s,a,300,300/80 * 60, 300*3/5,bus).
edge(s,a,300,300/100 * 60, 300*2/5,car).
edge(s,a,300,300/5 * 60, 300*0,walk).

edge(s,d,20,20/500 * 60, 20*1,plane).
edge(s,d,20,20/120 * 60, 20*3/4,train).
edge(s,d,20,20/80 * 60, 20*3/5,bus).
edge(s,d,20,20/100 * 60, 20*2/5,car).
edge(s,d,20,20/5 * 60, 20*0,walk).

edge(a,d,400,400/500 * 60, 400*1,plane).
edge(a,d,400,400/120 * 60, 400*3/4,train).
edge(a,d,400,400/80 * 60, 400*3/5,bus).
edge(a,d,400,400/100 * 60, 400*2/5,car).
edge(a,d,400,400/5 * 60, 400*0,walk).

edge(a,b,1500,1500/500 * 60, 1500*1, plane).
edge(a,b,1500,1500/120 * 60, 1500*3/4,train).
edge(a,b,1500,1500/80 * 60, 1500*3/5,bus).
edge(a,b,1500,1500/100 * 60,1500*2/5, car).
edge(a,b,1500,1500/5 * 60, 1500*0,walk).

edge(b,c,9,9/500 * 60, 9*1,plane).
edge(b,c,9,9/120 * 60, 9*3/4,train).
edge(b,c,9,9/80 * 60, 9*3/5,bus).
edge(b,c,9,9/100 * 60,9*2/5, car).
edge(b,c,9,9/5 * 60, 9*0,walk).

edge(b,e,200,200/500 * 60, 200*1, plane).
edge(b,e,200,200/120 * 60, 200*3/4,train).
edge(b,e,200,200/80 * 60, 200*3/5,bus).
edge(b,e,200,200/100 * 60, 200*2/5,car).
edge(b,e,200,200/5 * 60, 200*0,walk).

edge(c,d,2000,2000/500 * 60, 2000 * 1,plane).
edge(c,d,2000,2000/120 * 60, 2000 * 3/4,train).
edge(c,d,2000,2000/80 * 60, 2000 * 3/5,bus).
edge(c,d,2000,2000/100 * 60, 2000 * 2/5,car).
edge(c,d,2000,2000/5 * 60, 2000 * 0,walk). 

edge(c,g,12,12/500 * 60, 12 * 1,plane).
edge(c,g,12,12/120 * 60, 12 * 3/4,train).
edge(c,g,12,12/80 * 60, 12 * 3/5,bus).
edge(c,g,12,12/100 * 60, 12 * 2/5,car).
edge(c,g,12,12/5 * 60, 12 *0 ,walk).

edge(d,e,3,3/500 * 60, 3*  1,plane).
edge(d,e,3,3/120 * 60, 3 * 3/4,train).
edge(d,e,3,3/80 * 60, 3 * 3/5,bus).
edge(d,e,3,3/100 * 60, 3 * 2/5,car).
edge(d,e,3,3/5 * 60, 3 * 0,walk).

edge(e,f,400,400/500 * 60, 400 * 1,plane).
edge(e,f,400,400/120 * 60, 400 * 3/4,train).
edge(e,f,400,400/80 * 60, 400 * 3/5,bus).
edge(e,f,400,400/100 * 60, 400 * 2/5,car).
edge(e,f,400,400/5 * 60, 400 * 0,walk).

edge(f,g,800,800/500 * 60, 800 * 1,plane).
edge(f,g,800,800/120 * 60, 800 * 3/4,train).
edge(f,g,800,800/80 * 60, 800 * 3/5,bus).
edge(f,g,800,800/100 * 60, 800 * 2/5,car).
edge(f,g,800,800/5 * 60, 800 * 0,walk).


connected(X,Y,D,T,C) :- edge(X,Y,D,T,C,M) ; edge(Y,X,D,T,C,M).

path(A,B,D,T,C,Path) :- 
    travel(A,B,D,T,C,[A],Q), 
    reverse(Q,Path).

travel(A,B,D,T,C,P,[B|P]) :-
    connected(A,B,D,T,C).

travel(A,B,D,T,C,Visited,Path) :-
    connected(A,X,D1,T1,C1),
    X \== B,
    \+member(X,Visited),
    travel(X,B,D2,T2,C2,[X|Visited],Path),
    D is D1 + D2,
    T is T1 + T2,
    C is C1 + C2.
```

I wish to know the mode of transport for the selected paths.

I am not able to add it to a list.

So, if I query like

```
| ? - path(s,e,D,T,C,P,M), T<3.
```

gives me a list corresponding to each path describing the modes of transport

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if your variable names were more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From graph data it seems there are many different ways to move from, say, `s` to `e`.

Usually graph data is used *while* computing the path, also to avoid eventual useless solutions. Your predicate `path` already has many arguments, then I show a dumb post search mapping: say you got a path like [a, b, c], then *all* lists of available transport modes are enumerated with

```
transport_mode([X,Y|R], [M|Ms]):-
   ( edge(X,Y,_,_,_,M) ; edge(Y,X,_,_,_,M) ),
   transport_mode([Y|R], Ms).
transport_mode([_], []).
```

**edit** if you have library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/aggregate.html%27%29%29)) (available in SWI-Prolog or Yap), the minimum distance path can be computed this way:

```
?- aggregate_all(min(D, P), (path(s,e,D,T,C,P), T < 3), Min).
```

Comment: No I want to show the transport modes along with the paths. For eg. If the path(P) is [s,d,e], I wish the mode(M) to be [plane, walk] or [plane, train] and so on

Comment: seems working: `?- path(s,e,D,T,C,P),T<3,transport_mode(P,M).
D = C, C = 23,
T = 2.76,
P = [s, d, e],
M = [plane, plane] ;
D = C, C = 23,
T = 2.76,
P = [s, d, e],
M = [plane, train] ;
`...

Comment: oh..yeah thanks a lot! Just one more thing, is there a way to get the solution with least distance or least time?

Comment: yes, but then you should change your algorithm (it's already rather slow, from my test) pushing inside (as far as possible) the heuristic. See for instance this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11791840/874024), you'll find my code (targeting SWI-Prolog attributed variables) or some reference to more generic Prolog

Comment: Yes, I agree that my algorithm is quite slow. But since, I am new to prolog could you suggest how to push inside the heuristic.