# Performance issues on prolog

Tags: performance, path, prolog, shortest-path

I'm currently implementing an prolog program to calculate the shortest path between two points.
The framework exists already in a Java project. As a requirement the path must be implemented in prolog.
Therefore I use gnu.prolog (http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/)

Out of java I call `searchPath(1,5,Path)` which will return `Path=[5,4,3,2,1]`

Here is my prolog code:

```
:- dynamic(path/3).

findPath( [Goal | Rest], Goal, Temp, Temp, [Goal | Rest]).

findPath( [A | Rest], Goal, Cost, Temp, Path) :-
    path(A,B,C),
    \+member(B, [A | Rest]),
    NewCosts is (Temp + C),
    findPath([B, A | Rest], Goal, Cost, NewCosts, Path).

searchPath(Start,Goal,Path_to_goal) :-
    findPath([Start], Goal, Cost1, 0, Path),
    findPath([Start], Goal, Cost2, 0, Path2),
    Cost1=<Cost2,
    Path_to_goal = Path.
```

I have two issues with that:

1. The `searchPath` method **should return the shortest path**. However it
   does **NOT**. This results in the fact that my ghost "decides" to switch
   direction at some point resulting in the ghost jittering from left
   to right.
2. My prolog code takes up to **6 seconds** to return a result. I
   don't have to tell you that this is far too much time. However sometimes prolog only needs **19ms**. I wasn't able to figure out on which circumstances this depends on. For example a path list containing 99 elements takes 19ms to calculate but the 6 seconds were spent on a list containing only 38 elements.

Can you suggest any improvements?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Dijkstra' algorithm. I implemented it [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11791840/874024) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11787719/874024) question. My code uses [attributed variables](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%281,%276%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/extvar.html%27%29%29), I think should work in GnuProlog (I'll test now). Anyway, there you'll find the [link](http://colin.barker.pagesperso-orange.fr/lpa/dijkstra.htm) to a working pure Prolog implementation.

*edit* well, I think you could correct your code, because there is a problem:

`Path2` in `searchPath`/3 it's a *singleton*: then you clearly are going to *always* end with the first Path, and because the second findPath/3 will find *always* (if database doesn't change) the very same Cost and Path as the first, `Cost1=<Cost2,` will be always true. You could try if

```
searchPath(Start,Goal,Path_to_goal) :-
    findall(Cost-Path, findPath([Start], Goal, Cost, 0, Path), Paths),
    sort(Paths, [_-Path_to_goal|_]).
```

is sufficiently fast for your assignment. Otherwise you'll need to implement an incremental search, not easy to do because Prolog 'returns' alternatives paths on backtracking, then forcing to use some kind of side effect to select the minimum value.

*more edit* findall/3 will result in code too much slow. I've coded something more efficient using non backtrackable assignment (I used SWI-Prolog nb_setarg/3, you should use setarg/3 in GProlog).

```
findPath(_Limit, [Goal | Rest], Goal, Temp, Temp, [Goal | Rest]) :- !.

findPath(Limit, [A | Rest], Goal, Cost, Temp, Path) :-
    path(A,B,C),
    \+member(B, Rest),
    NewCosts is (Temp + C),
    NewCosts < Limit,
    findPath(Limit, [B, A | Rest], Goal, Cost, NewCosts, Path).

% ?- searchPath(aberdeen, glasgow, Path, Length).
%
searchPath(Start, Goal, Path_to_goal, L) :-
    S = path_len([], 1000000),
    repeat,
    arg(2, S, Limit),
    (   findPath(Limit, [Start], Goal, Cost, 0, Path)
    ->  (   Cost < Limit
        ->  nb_setarg(1, S, Path),
        nb_setarg(2, S, Cost),
        fail
        )
    ;   true
    ),
    arg(1, S, Rev),
    reverse(Rev, Path_to_goal),
    arg(2, S, L).
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The code works perfect. But unfortunately there is a reason why it doesn't help me out: This project is an assignment for university and I'm not allowed to copy any code. The dijkstra algorithm is far to complex for me to reimplement :-(

Comment: Thank for investing so much time for me!!! Your implementation works fine! Nevertheless I have some questions you perhaps can answer: 1. Even after reading the manual I'm not really aware of the difference between `nb_setarg` and `setarg`. Is it right, that with `setarg` the Value is replaced if backtracking finds another solution but this won't happen with `nb_setarg`? 2. I cannot figure out why there is a `fail` and a `true` in your algorithm. Could you please explain their purpose?

Comment: these are peculiarities of Prolog. `fail` produces the next solution by findPath, but after it has produced the last one available, it will fail, and `true` will allow to complete the procedure. See -> at [control predicates](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.8%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/control.html%27%29%29). Unrelated: I think that repeat/0 could be removed.