# Retain variable while backtracking prolog

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I am trying to find the minimum cost of a path while retaining the variable `Min` over backtracking. The code below does not work, however it gives a slight idea over what I want.

The Min is variable which holds the current minimum value, when compared with the new `Total` if the `Total` is smaller then the `NewMin` should be Total. This is possible I send the `NewMin` as `Min` **foreward**. However, because I am relying on backtracking, the clause before forcefully fails, and hence all the values stored are lost.

```
calculate_cost(Start, [], CostList, Min, NewMin):-
  sum_list(CostList, Total),
  Total < Min,
  NewMin is Total.

calculate_cost(Start, Rest, CostList, Min, NewMin):-
  flatten(Rest, Places),
  [Next|Left] = Places,
  route(Start, Next, Cost),
  calculate_cost(Next, Left, [Cost|CostList], Min, NewMin),
  fail.
```

Now I want to essentially retain the `Min` variable till the programs ends, while making several comparisons.

**Note:** The predicate calculate_cost is called several times (a lot more than 1 million), so lists is not feasible as i've tried and I leads to `Out of global stack` exception.

*Assert option has also been tried, but it leads to the same problem.*

*The only option is to search through and keep the minimum.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep updated Path & MinCost when calculate_cost complete:

```
:- dynamic current_min/2. % Path, Cost

calculate_cost(Start, [], CostList, Min, NewMin):-
  sum_list(CostList, Total),
  Total < Min,
  NewMin is Total,
  (  current_min(CPath, CMin), CMin =< NewMin
  -> true
  ;  retract(current_min(_,_)), assert(current_min(NewPath, NewMin))).
```

I know NewPath isn't available now: see if you can change your program flow to make NewPath available to calculate_cost

BTW there is [Dijkstra algorithm available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787719/best-structure-graph-to-implement-dijkstra-in-prolog/11791840#11791840): why don't you use it ?

Comment: Hey, I do not want to opt for the assert option as I want to optimise the program as much as possible. Assert and retract as far as i know are a slow processes when it comes to millions of calls it.

Comment: use [nb_setval/nb_getval](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar) then. Just beware you need to initialize, or the first nb_getval will throw an error.

Comment: So, can this global variable be overwritten, lets say at one point the global variable `FinalMin` is 9, after a while a smaller value is discovered lets say 2. Can `FinalMin` be set to 2 then?