# Attributed variables: library interfaces / implementations / portability

Tags: prolog

When I was skimming some [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) related questions recently, I stumbled upon [this answer by @mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096124/how-to-represent-directed-cyclic-graph-in-prolog-with-direct-access-to-neighbour/10101483#10101483) to question [How to represent directed cyclic graph in Prolog with direct access to neighbour verticies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096124/how-to-represent-directed-cyclic-graph-in-prolog-with-direct-access-to-neighbour) .

So far, my personal experience with attributed variables in Prolog has been very limited. But the use-case given by @mat sparked my interest. So  I tried using it for answering another question, [ordering lists with constraint logic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214266/ordering-lists-with-constraint-logic-programming/29657722#29657722).

*First, the good news:* My first use of attributed variables worked out like I wanted it to.

*Then, the not so good news:* When I had posted by answer, I realized there were several API's and implementations for attributed variables in Prolog.

I feel I'm over my head here... In particular I want to know the following:

- What API's are in wide-spread use? Up to now, I found two: SICStus and SWI.
- Which features do the different attributed variable implementations offer? The same ones? Or does one subsume the other?
- Are there differences in semantics?
- What about the actual implementation? Are some more efficient than others?
- Can be (or is) using attributed variables a portability issue?

Lots of question marks, here... Please share your experience / stance? 
 Thank you in advance!

---

#### Edit 2015-04-22

Here's a code snippet of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214266/ordering-lists-with-constraint-logic-programming/29657722#29657722) mentioned above:

```
init_att_var(X,Z) :-
    put_attr(Z,value,X).

get_att_value(Var,Value) :-
    get_attr(Var,value,Value).
```

So far I "only" use [`put_attr/3` and `get_attr/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=attvar), but---according to the SICStus Prolog documentation on attributed variables---SICStus offers [`put_attr/2` and `get_attr/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002datts.html).

So even *this very shallow use-case*  *requires* some *emulation* layer (one way or the other).

Comment: Please do not forget the user's viewpoint. That is, the one who just uses  constraints! There `call_residue_vars/2` is of utmost importance.

Comment: ... and `copy_term/3`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would like to focus on one important general point I noticed when working with different interfaces for attributes variables: When designing an interface for attributed variables, an implementor should also keep in mind the following:

- Is it possible to take attributes into account when reasoning about **simultaneous unifications**, as in `[X,Y] = [0,1]`?

This is possible for example in SICStus Prolog, because such bindings are *undone* before `verify_attributes/3` is called. In the interface provided by hProlog (`attr_unify_hook/2`, called **after** the unification and with all bindings already in place) it is hard to take into account the (previous) attributes of `Y` when reasoning about the unification of `X` in `attr_unify_hook/2`, because `Y` is no longer a variable at this point! This may be sufficient for solvers that can make decisions based on ground values alone, but it is a serious limitation for solvers that need additional data, typically stored in attributes, to see whether a unification should succeed, and which are then no longer easily available. One obvious example: Boolean unification with decision diagrams.

As of 2016, the [**verify-attributes** branch](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/tree/verify-attributes) of SWI-Prolog also supports `verify_attributes/3`, thanks to great implementation work by [Douglas Miles](https://github.com/logicmoo). The branch is ready for testing and intended to be merged into master as soon as it works correctly and efficiently. For compatibility with hProlog, the branch also supports `attr_unify_hook/2`: It does so by rewriting such definitions to the more general `verify_attributes/3` at compilation time.

Performance-wise, it is clear that there may be a downside to `verify_attributes/3`, because making several variables ground at the same time may let you sooner see (in `attr_unify_hook/2`) that a unification cannot succeed. However, I will gladly and any time exchange this typically negligible advantage for the improved reliability, ease of use, and increased functionality that the more general interface gives you, and which is in any case already the standard behaviour in SICStus Prolog which is on top of its generality also one of the faster Prolog systems around.

SICStus Prolog also features an important predicate called `project_attributes/2`: It is used by the toplevel to project constraints to query variables. SWI-Prolog also supports this in recent versions.

There is also one huge advantage of the SWI interface: The residual goals that `attribute_goals//1` and hence `copy_term/3` give you are always a *list*. This helps users to avoid defaultyness in their code, and encourages a more declarative interface, because a list of pure constraint goals *cannot contain control structures*.

Interestingly, neither interface lets you interpret unifications other than *syntactically*. Personally, I think there are cases where you may want to interpret unifications differently than syntactically, however, there may also be good arguments against that.

The other interface predicates for attributed variables are mostly easily interchangable with simple wrapper predicates for different systems.

Comment: Quite ironically, the very mentioned features in the SICStus interface were called **fat** at ICLP 2008 in Udine.

Comment: Can you confirm that YAP has the same shortcoming as SWI?

Comment: Is the recent change in SWI now fulfilling this? - Please update your answer, just in case.

Answer (score 6):

Jekejeke Minlog has state-less or **thin** attribute variables. Well not exactly, an attribute variable can have zero, one or many hooks, which are allowed to be closures, and hence can carry a little state.

But typically an implementation manages the state elsewere. For this
purpose Jekejeke Minlog allows creating reference types from variables,
so that they can be used as indexes into tables.

The full potential is unleashed if this combined with trailing and/or
forward chaining. As an example we have implemented CLP(FD). There is also a little solver tutorial.

The primitive [ingredients](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/15_min/10_docu/02_reference/07_theory/05_system) in our case are:

1) State-less Attribute Variables
2) Trailing and Variable Keys
3) Continuation Queue

The attribute variables hooks might have binding effects upto extending the continuation queue but are only executed once. Goals from the continuation queue can be non-deterministic.

There are some additional layers before realizing applications, that are mostly aggregations of the primitives to make changes temporarily.

The main applications so far are open source [here](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/blog/en/docs/15_min/02_reference/finite) and [here](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/blog/en/docs/15_min/02_reference/term/package.jsp):

a) Finite Domain Constraint Solver
b) Herbrand Constraints
c) Goal Suspension

Bye

Comment: Edit: Since release 1.1.2 Jekejeke Prolog has also a continuation queue which allows implementing predicates such as freeze/2. So there is a new item 3) and a new example application c) in the post.

Answer (score 5):

An additional perspective on attributed variable libraries is how many attributes can be defined per module. In the case of SWI-Prolog/YAP and citing SWI documentation:

> Each attribute is associated to a module, and the hook
>   (`attr_unify_hook/2`) is executed in this module.

This is a severe limitation for implementers of libraries such as CLP(FD) as it forces using additional modules for the sole purpose of having multiple attributes instead of being able to define as many attributes as required in the module implementing their library. This limitation doesn't exist on the SICStus Prolog interface, which provides a directive `attribute/1` that allows the declaration of an arbitrary number of attributes per module.

Comment: Not exactly a severe limitation. It is pretty straightforward to implement many little attributes as arguments of a single per-module attribute.

Comment: @jschimpf True but that workaround is far from ideal. You go from attribute names to integers. Instead of accessing directly an attribute value, you need to access a mega-attribute value, a compound term, and then access one of its arguments using its position instead of an attribute name. Removing an attribute can imply re-shuffling the other attributes. These kind of changes will require propagation to any handler of that mega-attribute.

Answer (score 5):

You can find one of the oldest and most elaborate implementations of attributed variables in [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org), where it forms part of the wider infrastructure for implementing constraint solvers.

The main characteristics of this design are:

- attributes must be declared, and in return the compiler supports efficient access
- a syntax for attributed variables, so that they can be read and written
- a more complete set of handlers for attribute operations, so that attributes are not only taken into account for unification, but also for other generic operations such as term copying and subsumption tests
- a clear separation between the concepts of variable attribute and suspended goals
- used in over a dozen of ECLiPSe's libraries

[This paper (section 4)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4240) and the ECLiPSe documentation have more details.

Comment: @false He wrote "one of the oldest", not "the oldest".

Comment: These attribute variables can be read and written. Can they also be read when consulting a Prolog text as part of a clause? Can this clause be instantiated/used as one might expect?